# The selector "ng-component" did not match any elements error

Tags: angular, webpack

**Error:**

```
EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 caused by: The selector "ng-component" did not match any elements
```

App works fine while running with systemjs directly.
When i tried to build **globals.bundle.js** and **app.bundle.js** using webpack and deploy i get this error.

All files and dependency is loaded fine.

Here is my HTML

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Maven + Spring MVC</title>
    <base href="/survey-web/">
<spring:url value="/resources/core/css/hello.css" var="coreCss" />
<spring:url value="/resources/core/css/bootstrap.min.css" var="bootstrapCss" />
<link href="${bootstrapCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="${coreCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
<%--<script src="resources/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="resources/systemjs.config.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="resources/dist/globals.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/dist/app.bundle.js"></script>

<script>
    //System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
</html>
```

**Webpack config**

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
    globals: [
        'zone.js',
        'reflect-metadata'
    ],
    app: './app/main.ts',
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {test: /.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'},
    ]
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: './dist'
}
};
```

**Plunkr**

https://plnkr.co/edit/AfYGsdHpIVnVnuF7BCUJ?p=preview
Though it happens only in webpack build in my local environment, i can reproduce this through plnkr

Comment: Where did you use `<ng-component>`? Perhaps you meant to use `<ng-container>`?

Comment: I never used <ng-component> any where

Comment: Angular uses it as `defaultComponentElementName` (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/33910ddfc98d092e514d90a2cec3b5daaf3d4277/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.ts#L355). No idea what can cause this error.

Comment: some of my component doesn't have "selector", since i am using it for routing. Couldt that cause this error? i even tried selector: ''

Comment: That could be. There was an issue and I thought it was fixed, that components without selectors should work for routing (and other situations where `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` is used) but I'm not sure and there might be a regression.

Comment: Update: It works fine, if i remove route and have a selector with component.

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1662#issuecomment-98928582 "This is obsolete, and no longer relevant / actionable." doesn't sound like "fixed" I think this is worth a bug report. Either a proper warning, or properly working without a selector.

Comment: Thank you for finding the history of issues, i have added a comment there...
Hoping some one will respond.
Mean while i am modifying my code (with no hope) to see if i can fix something.

Comment: Comments on closed issues are mostly ignored. It would be better to create a new issue (with a Plunker to reproduce if possible) and a link to the old issue.

Comment: Update: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14026

Comment: They usually want a Plunker to reproduce. Would be great if you could add one. Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular2 template under the `new` button.

Comment: but how do i configure and build webpack in plunker!!

Comment: Sorry, forgot about this being only with webpack deployment. I don't know a way to use webpack with Plunker either. It's usually still appreciated if a full example is provided so they can see what exactly your application looks like that causes your problem, even when the error itself can not be directly reproduced. Such things just increase the chances a lot that someone will have a closer look at your issue.

Comment: Plunkr link updated, surprisingly i can reproduce in plunkr even without webpack.

Comment: This is why Plunkers for bug reports are so much appreciated. Creating them usually reveals more information even when it doesn't seem obvious why :). Very helpful !!

Comment: If you bootstrap AppComponent then you need to have the appropriate selector in your html. In this case you didn't specify selector then it will be default selector(`ng-component`). https://plnkr.co/edit/xhAyEI600OpR3oUsQ9D3?p=preview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you **@Günter Zöchbauer** and **@yurzui** for your support

@yurzui now i understand that i need to have a selector for bootstrap component or use

```
<body>
    <ng-component></ng-component>
</body>
```

instead of

```
<body>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
```

How ever it is stange why it would work if i am using systemjs and doestn't work with plunkr or webpack.

Comment: To add some clarification, this is because you defined an ['entry-component'](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-entry-component-defined) in your module, without including a selector on it to tell Angular where to render it. To solve this, either define a selector and include the relevant element in the HTML, or omit the selector and use the generic `<ng-component>` selector (rare). Alternatively, you can omit the entry component completely (remove `.bootstrap()` or `.entry()` from your `@NgModule` and switch to the route based `<router-outlet>` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Another clarification, if you use `Angular Cli` to create your application and you change the selector for your root component let's say from "`app-root`" to "`root`", you will have to go to the main html page which is `index.html` and change the template within the body tag too. If not, you will get a similar error like the one above. That is from

`<body>
 <app-root></app-root>
 </body>` **to**

`<body>
 <root></root>
 </body>`

Answer (score 2):

After experiencing this problem, for me, it turns out that **you can't put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the index.html**.

So instead, I had to create a top-level module SOLELY to hold the router-outlet:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent{}
```

In the future I'll probably build out the top-level app more, but, as I'm just learning, this burned an hour. "Let's implement routing now," I thought to myself. "Should be as easy as ...."

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue just now and that was because of 

   `bootstrap: [
      AppComponent,
AdminComponent
   ]`

Only have one Bootstrap Component

DEFAULT should be

   `bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]`

Answer (score 2):

I've found it's usually because the `index.html` has an incorrect reference to the `app.component.ts` selector.

It should match (like this)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one component in bootstrap

bootstrap : [
AppComponent
]